# Anything similar to Apple's sync services or Microsoft's sync framework?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, syncservices

I'm looking for anything that facilitates syncing local data with some server on the internet. It doesn't have to be as mature as those two and any platform is fine, I'm just looking at different approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know of that provides a reasonable set of features and architecture is the OpenSync project: http://www.opensync.org/

It doesn't look too active though, which is unfortunate. It may offer a good model for the problem you're trying to solve (which, depending on the data, could be difficult). Good luck.